# How do I achieve this look?

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I'm trying to get a quite distinctive look to show off a model, like this:[image]

It's sort of like a silhouette, but with the lines showing.
I can add the glow and texture in photoshop, I'm really just concerned about the lines.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: First I would try to give it black material with full roughness, then add Freestyle lines with white color to get those lines... You can get those dots all over the place with composition (placing image like that above it) 
But I'm not sure how to highlight some of those top faces, maybe with some strong light

Comment: with Fresnel you can get something that is close to what you show, but without the lines

Comment: Sorry guys, it looks like I wasn't clear enough in my question. I figured it out though.
I made a separate wireframe mesh and gave it an emission material, then got rid of all light in the scene. Now only the wireframe is visible, and I'll put in highlights if I need them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To get the lines. you could use Freestyle for selected edges / boundaries. and/or do edge-detection on normal / depth passes in the compositor, or external app. for the intersection between objects, which Freestyle does not pick up.